# Dimensions: $\bigcap^{k}_{i=1}V_i \neq \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and let $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_k \subset V$ be subspaces of 
$V$. Assume that

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum^{k}_{i=1} \dim(V_i) > n(k-1).
\end{eqnarray}

To show that $\bigcap^{k}_{i=1}V_i \neq \{0\}$, what must be done? Also, could there be an accompanying schematic/diagram to show the architecture of the spaces' form; that is, something like what's shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365762/properties-of-subspace-sums).

Comment: I think there is a general outline as to what's going on here in Hoffman's "Linear Algebra" on page 209. I'm just having difficulty bringing everything together.

Comment: It certainly would be interesting to see a diagram of what *exactly* the subspace/vector space containment arragement looks like. Something like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Tn3CgLBhex8/UW-ZIiJhy2I/AAAAAAAAAVM/On8iCvcNDIM/w762-h428-p-o/Untitled.jpg).

Comment: Just curious: the Seirios's answer is perfect; but is it possible to show this proposition by the PIE?

Comment: @Seirios Unfortunately, I'm most likely not allowed to use material too much outside my professor's closed-form lecture notes.

Comment: @Seirios If it is not too taxing, perhaps you could wind out what you've propounded in terms more native to the simple, elementary content of an honors linear algebra course.

Comment: @Taro Out of curiosity, what is "the PIE"?

Comment: @EuYu the (P)rinciple of (I)nclusion and (E)xclusion.

Comment: @ScottH. Ah. Strangely I think that is the first time I've ever seen it abbreviated like that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma:** Let $W_1,\ \cdots,\ W_k\subset V$. Then
$$\dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}W_i\right)\ge \sum_{i=1}^k\dim(W_i) - (k-1)n$$
**Proof:** First, recall the following equation relating the dimension of the intersection to the dimension of the sum.
$$\dim(W_1 + W_2) + \dim(W_1\cap W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2)$$
Since $W_1,\ W_2\subset V$ it follows that $W_1 + W_2\subseteq V$ and therefore $\dim(W_1+W_2)\le n$. We then have
$$\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \ge \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - n$$
This is our base case. Let us proceed to prove via induction. Suppose the inequality holds for $k\ge 2$ and consider $k+1$. Then
$$\dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k+1}W_i\right) = \dim\left(W_{k+1}\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^kW_i\right)$$
By the base case, the above satisfies
$$\dim\left(W_{k+1}\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^kW_i\right) \ge \dim(W_{k+1}) + \dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^kW_i\right)-n$$
By the inductive hypothesis, we then have
$$\dim(W_{k+1}) + \dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^kW_i\right)-n \ge \dim(W_{k+1}) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^k\dim(W_i) - (k-1)n\right) - n$$
Combining, we of course have
$$\dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k+1}W_i\right) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\dim(W_i) - kn$$
The proposition follows by mathematical induction. $\square$

Now your result immediately follows since
$$\sum_{i=1}^k W_i > (k-1)n \implies \dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k W_i\right) \ge \sum_{i=1}^k\dim(W_i) - (k-1)n > 0$$

Comment: +1 for elementary solution. BTW how do you come up with that lemma? Comparing the hypothesis and the conclusion? (Since I cannot feel the lemma is true intuitively.)

Comment: @Taro I immediately had the idea of using the identity $$\dim(W) + \dim(V) = \dim(W\cap V) + \dim(W +V)$$ since it's one of the main results which relate vectors spaces to their intersection. The natural way to get rid of the $W+V$ term in the above is to bound it above by the dimension of the ambient space. That gives the case $k=2$. The generalization to $k>2$ is also quite natural I think.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I also thought in that direction. For $k = 3$, it becomes $$\dim(V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3) = \dim(V) - \dim(V_1) - \dim(V_2) - \dim(V_3) + \dim(V_1 \cap V_2) + \dim(V_2 \cap V_3) + \dim(V_1 \cap V_3).$$ That's why I mentioned to the PIE in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

For $1 \leq i \leq k$, let $p_i : V \to V/V_i$ be the canonical projection. Now, consider the morphism $\varphi = p_1 \times \dots \times p_k : V \to \prod\limits_{i=1}^k V/V_i$; notice that $\text{ker}(\varphi)= \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k V_i$.

But $\dim \big( \prod\limits_{i=1}^k V/V_i \big) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \left( \dim(V)-\dim(V_i) \right)<n$. Therefore, $\varphi$ cannot be injective, hence $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k V_i \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more explicit.

Comment: @Trancot : what do you mean ? How could it be made “more explicit” than this ? I do not think it can.

Comment: @Trancot: Is there something you don't understand?

Comment: @Seirios Yes, well, no. I wouldn't say "not understand," but maybe "not familiar yet." I have to do a bit more combing through textbooks and the like to see what you're really saying.

Comment: @Trancot: If you want, you can take $p_i : V \to W_i$, where $V= V_i \oplus W_i$ and then $\varphi : V \to \prod\limits_{i=1}^k W_i$. It is equivalent.

Comment: @Seirios Proof by counter example anyone?

Comment: @Seirios If it is not too taxing, perhaps you could wind out what you've propounded in terms more native to the simple, elementary content of an honors linear algebra course.

Comment: @Trancot Dear Trancot, the intuition behind Seirios's answer is the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The second paragraph comes from the following fact: There is no injective map $T : V \to W$ when $\dim V > \dim W$.

Answer (score 5):

First write the equation in the form
$$
  n>\sum_{i=1}^k\bigl(n-\dim V_i\bigr)
$$
so that you can get some idea of what it really says: the codimensions of the subspaces $V_i$ add up to less than the dimension of the whole space. Now the codimension of a subspace gives the number of linear equations needed to define the subspace. If we choose such a set of equations for each subspace $V_i$, and take together all equations thus obtained, we have fewer equations than $n=\dim V$. This means (by the rank-nullity theorem if you like) that there is some nonzero vector that satisfies all equations at once. This vector lies in $\bigcap_{i=1}^kV_i$.

*Added, to address comments by OP.* To obtain from the inequality given in the question the one I gave above, first write the right hand side  of the former as $nk-n$, then the term $nk$ as $\sum_{i=1}n$, now move the summation on the left to the right hand side, integrating its terms $\dim V_i$ as $-\dim V_i$ into the summation just created, and finally move the term $-n$ to the left, becoming $n$. The inequality remains a strict "$>$" throughout these manipulations. As for the fact that the codimension of a subspace equals the number of equations needed to define it, that is a basic fact from linear algebra: if you got a list of homogeneous linear equations (right hand side is $0$), then each new equation decreases the dimension of the solution space by $1$, unless it is linearly dependent of the previous equations, in which case one can drop the new equation. If you want a more formal argument for this, choose a basis of $d=\dim V_i$ vectors for the subspace $V_i$, extend it by $n-d$ more vectors to a basis of the whole space (incomplete basis theorem); then consider the $n$ coordinate functions for this basis, and the $n-d$ equations setting the last $n-d$ coordinates to $0$, which gives a system whose solution is precisely $V_i$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\leq$ the dimension of the whole space?

Comment: or anyone else reading this comment, could you explain how the summation equation reduces to this?

Comment: Could you expound on your comment "Now the codimension of a subspace gives the number of linear equations needed to define the subspace," please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take complements. That is, pick vector spaces $W_i$ with $\dim(W_i) + \dim(V_i) = n$ and $W_i \cap V_i = \{0\}$.

EDIT: thanks, Ted

Comment: Should be $W_i \cap V_i = \{0\}$.

Comment: @Ted, Oops, and thanks!

Comment: I really don't see what you could do with subspaces $W_i$. Unless you consider the projections onto the $W_i$ parallel to the $V_i$ and combine them to a linear map to the _external_ direct sum of the $W_i$ (a rather non-obvious thing to do, it is really not clear that you hinted at this), in which case the argument reduces to that of Serios.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Can you do the case where $k = 2$? Then try induction on $k$, that involves replacing $V_1,V_2$ by $V_1 \cap V_2$, using the identity $\dim( V_1 + V_2) + \dim V_1 \cap V_2 = \dim V_1 + \dim V_2$.